# Setting path X in "ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile("X");"

Tags: java, servlets, zip

I'm having problems setting the path of the zip file, X, in `ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile("X");`.

I don't want to hardcode the path such that it becomes `ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile("C:/docs/data.zip");`.
I want to do something like :

```
ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/" + request.getAttribute("myFile").toString());
```

Where the path of the zip file is determined by the selection of the user. But, this gives an error, because this only works for InputStream.

Previously, I've already retrieved the multipart/form data and gotten the real path of the zip file:

```
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF");
UploadBean bean = new UploadBean();
bean.setFolderstore(path);
MultipartFormDataRequest multiPartRequest = new MultipartFormDataRequest(request);
bean.store(multiPartRequest); //store in WEB-INF

// get real path / name of zip file which is store in the WEB-INF
Hashtable files = multiPartRequest.getFiles();
UploadFile upFile = (UploadFile) files.get("file");
if (upFile != null) request.setAttribute("myFile", upFile.getFileName());
```

Any solutions to this?

Comment: What's the functional requirement? Send the file to user for download? If so, why is `InputStream` insufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you don't use the real path that you already have.

Anyway, you can work with a `ZipInputStream`.

This way you can handle your file as a simple Stream. The only big differences are the `getName()` method and `size()` that you can't directly access. With a ZIS you will be able to read every entry.

---

**Resources :**

- [Javadoc - ZipInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert webcontent-relative paths to absolute disk file system paths in two ways:

1. Just use [`ServletContext#getRealPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) as you previously already did.

   ```
   ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/" + request.getAttribute("myFile").toString()));
   ```
2. Use [`ServletContext#getResource()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) instead. It returns an `URL`. Call `getPath()` on it.

   ```
   ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(getServletContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/" + request.getAttribute("myFile").toString()).getPath());
   ```

Way #1 is preferred.

Comment: +1 for this solution. But like I said, I really don't understand why the question is asked whereas the solution is already in the snippet the OP gave.

Comment: @Colin: Some people only copypaste without actually understanding what each line of code does.